# Races when piping two commands to a named pipe

Tags: bash, pipe

I want to have one process reading from a named pipe that receives data from multiple sources:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/p
```

But I can't figure out how to get it to work consistently.

### First Scenario - this works

**tty1**:

Set up two processes to write to my fifo; both of these will block:

```
$ echo 'first' > /tmp/p; echo 'second' > /tmp/p
```

**tty2**:

Read from the pipe:

```
$ cat /tmp/p
first
second
```

This still works if I execute the above in reverse order

My problem comes when I have two separate commands that I want to come out of the pipe:

### Second Scenario - does not work

**first.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'first' > /tmp/p
```

**second.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'second' > /tmp/p
```

**tty1**

```
$ sh first.sh; sh second.sh
```

**tty2**

```
$ cat /tmp/p
first
```

The execution of `sh second.sh` from my first tty will block indefinitely, until something else reads from the named pipe.

### What I think is happening

From http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe:

> If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have been closed, then an attempt to read(2) from the pipe will see end-of-file (read(2) will return 0)

So when `echo` exits in `first.sh`, the shell executing it closes the file descriptor for `/tmp/p`, which means that `cat` in my second TTY sees EOF.

How do I get around this with the shell? Is there a way to keep a reference to the read end of the named pipe around in my main controlling script, so that it doesn't get closed when sub-shells exit? In practise, I will be passing the path to the named pipe to the sub-shells. Do I need to just make my subshells output to their own stdout and perform a redirection on them?

I feel like there's something I'm missing here. Using named pipes has been simple and straightforward for everything I've tried to do aside from this case.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but looks like you're trying to fix the write side of things when it's the read side that needs fixing. Shouldn't your reader loop back to waiting until whatever you're doing is done?

Comment: Don't redirect in the scripts, run the scripts like this `(first.sh;second.sh) > /tmp/p`

Comment: From the point of view of simplicity, there is nothing broken about the read side. In practise I will connect this pipe to the stdin of a process that does some stream processing and writes stuff out; EOF on STDIN is EOF on STDIN.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just do:

```
{ echo foo; echo bar;} > /tmp/p
```

If you want your controlling script to leave the pipe open, you can do:

```
exec 3<> /tmp/p
```

Opening a named pipe in read-write mode is to avoid that to block if the pipe hasn't been opened yet. That would instantiate it if it wasn't yet. It works on Linux at least but is not guaranteed to by POSIX.

Alternatively (and portably):

```
: < /tmp/p & exec 3> /tmp/p
```

Then instead of having each process open the named pipe, you can also do:

```
cmd >&3
```

And in the end, you'd do:

```
exec 3>&-
```

To close the writing end to let readers know it's finished.

change all `<`s to `>`s and `<`s to `>`s if you need the logic to be the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reliably use cat for reading from named pipes as you are discovering. I had the exact same problem a few years ago, and wrote [pcat](https://github.com/seveas/hacks/blob/master/pcat.c) to overcome this limitation.

Comment: That has nothing to do with `cat` here and your `pcat` can be written `cat p 3> p` and would never return.

Answer (score 0):

You just misunderstand how cat works. The exiting of echo makes cat exit, too. So if you cannot force your writing processes to open the pipe rw (and keep it open) then you simply have to call cat in a loop:

```
while true; do cat /tmp/p || break; done
```

break becomes active when you cancel cat with e.g. ^C.

Comment: I understand this; the issue that I have is that cat is seeing EOF on the pipe in the first place. I need to control the behaviour so that i can redirect the output of N processes to the write end of the pipe before it's closed (ie before the reader, in this case cat, sees EOF).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to manually keep open a pseudo writing reference to the fifo (using `tail -f /dev/null 1>fifo` or `cat fifo 3>fifo`) so that the reading end of the fifo won't close down after the first read.

```
# tty1
bash -c '
mkfifo fifo || exit 1
tail -f /dev/null 1>fifo &
#0<&- cat fifo 3>fifo &
#lsof -p $!
echo first > fifo
echo second > fifo
kill $!
'

# tty2
cat fifo
```